# Jest Unit Tests Fail When Test Directory Search Location Is Changed

Tags: jestjs

I am encountering an odd problem with jest: changing where jest looks for its test files appears to break the tests.

I've narrowed it down to a very small reproducable case.

- This jest configuration, set in our `package.json` succeeds:

  ```
  "jest": {
    "testFileExtensions": ["jest"],
    "testPathDirs": ["Views/Test"],
    "scriptPreprocessor": "Views/Test/preprocessor.js",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [ "js", "jsx" ],
    "unmockedModulePathPatterns": [ "react" ]
  }
  ```

  Like so:

  ```
  npm info it worked if it ends with ok
  npm info using npm@2.2.0
  npm info using node@v0.10.33
  npm info pretest outfits@0.0.0
  npm info test outfits@0.0.0

  > outfits@0.0.0 test C:\tfs\Nordstrom.Outfits\Nordstrom.Outfits
  > jest

  Using Jest CLI v0.2.2
  Waiting on 2 tests...
  PASS  Views\Test\__tests__\Components\Outfit\Description\Description.jest (3.164s)
  Waiting on 1 test...
  PASS  Views\Test\__tests__\Components\Outfit\GetTheLook\GetTheLook.jest (4.475s)
  2 tests passed (2 total)
  Run time: 5.339s
  npm info posttest outfits@0.0.0
  npm info ok
  ```
- This jest configuration causes one of the two tests to fail. The only change is changing the root of where it looks for the `__tests__` directory(ies).

  ```
  "jest": {
    "testFileExtensions": ["jest"],
    "testPathDirs": ["Views"],
    "scriptPreprocessor": "Views/Test/preprocessor.js",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [ "js", "jsx" ],
    "unmockedModulePathPatterns": [ "react" ]
  }
  ```

  With an oddball exception that looks like this (elided for brevity and reflowed for readability):

  ```
  Using Jest CLI v0.2.2
  Waiting on 2 tests...
   PASS  Views\Test\__tests__\Components\Outfit\Description\Description.jest (3.108s)
  Waiting on 1 test...
   FAIL  Views\Test\__tests__\Components\Outfit\GetTheLook\GetTheLook.jest (3.233s)
  ● Get the look to › it encountered a declaration exception
    - TypeError:
        C:\tfs\Nordstrom.Outfits\Nordstrom.Outfits\node_modules\nord\flux.js:
        C:\tfs\Nordstrom.Outfits\Nordstrom.Outfits\node_modules\nord\core\actions.js:
        C:\tfs\Nordstrom.Outfits\Nordstrom.Outfits\node_modules\nord\util\useGlobal.js:
        C:\tfs\Nordstrom.Outfits\Nordstrom.Outfits\node_modules\nord\util\object\getDeepProperty.js:
        C:\tfs\Nordstrom.Outfits\Nordstrom.Outfits\node_modules\nord\util\object\result.js:
        C:\tfs\Nordstrom.Outfits\Nordstrom.Outfits\node_modules\nord\node_modules\lodash-node\compat\object\result.js:
        C:\tfs\Nordstrom.Outfits\Nordstrom.Outfits\node_modules\nord\node_modules\lodash-node\compat\lang\isFunction.js:
        C:\tfs\Nordstrom.Outfits\Nordstrom.Outfits\node_modules\nord\node_modules\lodash-node\compat\lang\isNative.js:

        Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined
          at C:\tfs\Nordstrom.Outfits\Nordstrom.Outfits\node_modules\nord\node_modules\lodash-node\compat\lang\isNative.js:27:4
          at Object.runContentWithLocalBindings (C:\tfs\Nordstrom.Outfits\Nordstrom.Outfits\node_modules\jest-cli\src\lib\utils.js:357:17)
          at Loader._execModule (C:\tfs\Nordstrom.Outfits\Nordstrom.Outfits\node_modules\jest-cli\src\HasteModuleLoader\HasteModuleLoader.js:245:9)
          at Loader.requireModule (C:\tfs\Nordstrom.Outfits\Nordstrom.Outfits\node_modules\jest-cli\src\HasteModuleLoader\HasteModuleLoader.js:900:12)
          at Loader._generateMock (C:\tfs\Nordstrom.Outfits\Nordstrom.Outfits\node_modules\jest-cli\src\HasteModuleLoader\HasteModuleLoader.js:276:30)
          at Loader.requireMock (C:\tfs\Nordstrom.Outfits\Nordstrom.Outfits\node_modules\jest-cli\src\HasteModuleLoader\HasteModuleLoader.js:796:43)
          at Loader.requireModuleOrMock (C:\tfs\Nordstrom.Outfits\Nordstrom.Outfits\node_modules\jest-cli\src\HasteModuleLoader\HasteModuleLoader.js:919:17)
          at C:\tfs\Nordstrom.Outfits\Nordstrom.Outfits\node_modules\nord\node_modules\lodash-node\compat\lang\isFunction.js:2:16
          ...
          at Suite.<anonymous> (C:\tfs\Nordstrom.Outfits\Nordstrom.Outfits\Views\Test\__tests__\Components\Outfit\GetTheLook\GetTheLook.jest:5:13)
          at env.describe_ (<anonymous>:40:25)
          at env.describe (<anonymous>:27:19)
          at describe (C:\tfs\Nordstrom.Outfits\Nordstrom.Outfits\node_modules\jest-cli\vendor\jasmine\jasmine-1.3.0.js:604:27)
          at C:\tfs\Nordstrom.Outfits\Nordstrom.Outfits\Views\Test\__tests__\Components\Outfit\GetTheLook\GetTheLook.jest:4:1
          ...
          at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
  1 test failed, 1 test passed (2 total)
  Run time: 4.108s
  npm info outfits@0.0.0 Failed to exec test script
  npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
  ```

Our source tree (also elided for brevity) looks like this:

```
<rootDir>/
|
+- package.json
|
+-node_modules/
| |
| +-gulp/
| +-jest/
| +-react
| +-...
|
+-Views/
  |
  +-Components/
  | |
  | +-Description/Description.jsx
  | +-GetTheLook/GetTheLook.jsx
  |
  +-Test/
    |
    +- preprocessor.js
    |
    +- __tests__/
       |
       +-Components/
         |
         +-Outfit/
           |
           +-Description/Description.jest
           +-GetTheLook/GetTheLook.jest
```